# Redirect to https. Conflict with two domains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two sites on the same hosting. Each one is in a different folder and each one has its own domain.

- Site1. It has https.
- Site2. It has not https, only http.

If I put a .htaccess in the root of Site1 folder the addresses of site2 also are redirected to its address in https. In the Site2 I have no .htaccess

This is the code that I have in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Why does it happen and how to redirect from http to https only on Site1?

Comment: Can we see the htaccess file? At least the pertinent portions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a condition to make this rule specific to `site1`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?site1\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Change `site1` to your actual site name and don't forget to test in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: I added `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?site1\. [NC]` line, rest you already have as per question. That line is a condition that returns true if `HTTP_HOST` variable is `www.site1` or `site1` as starting `www` is optional.

Comment: In the last line you write only "^" to search, why?

Comment: `^` means start position that always returns true since want to match all URIs. `^(.*)$` in your regex also does the same but it has a redundant group and bit longer than needed regex. btw did this work for you?